# 2 jars generation from 2 profiles for different OS

Tags: maven, jar, swt

I am trying to create 2 jars from 2 approaches(Profiles and executiosn)
My target is to create both macJar.jar and windowsJar.jar which should have os specific swt dependency in it.

Is this possible from below appr?

**Approach 1: Using profiles**
**Command:** mvn clean install -Pwindows,mac  **or** mvn clean install -Pmac,windows  **or** mvn clean install -P windows,mac (space after -P)
**Obeservations:** In either commands approach only one jar is created with 'windowsJar.jar' .

```
    <profiles>
      <profile>
            <id>windows</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <jarName>windowsJar</jarName>
                <swt.groupId>org.eclipse.swt.org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86.4.3.swt</swt.groupId>
                <swt.artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86</swt.artifactId>
                <swt.version>4.5</swt.version>
            </properties>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>org.test.test1.Mainclass</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <finalName>${jarName}</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>

                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>make-assembly</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>

                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    </profile>

    <profile>
            <id>mac</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <jarName>macJAR</jarName>
                <swt.groupId>org.eclipse.swt.org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64.4.3.swt</swt.groupId>
                <swt.artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64</swt.artifactId>
                <swt.version>4.5</swt.version>
            </properties>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

                    <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
<mainClass>org.test.test1.Mainclass</mainClass>

                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <finalName>${jarName}</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>make-assembly</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

**Approach 2: Using executions**
**Command:** mvn clean install 
**Obeservations:** In either commands approach only one jar is created with 'windowsJar.jar' .

```
              <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                 <mainClass>org.test.test1.Mainclass</mainClass>

                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>mac-make-assembly</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
<configuration>
             <classifier>mac</classifier>
           </configuration>

                        </execution>

                        <execution>
                            <id>windows-make-assembly</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
             <classifier>windows</classifier>
           </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: Why are you using a profile for that? You just need to configure 2 executions of the `maven-assembly-plugin` both with their respective configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried using executions with classfiers. Then 2 jars get created. But I need swt jars also in the final jar. I dont know how to pass swt jar dependency from execution aproach. I updated the code which i tried using executions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a maven build each property can have only one value. Defining a property value a 2nd time ends up overriding the first value, not splitting a project build into two branches. So when you activate two profiles and they both modify property value, one of them overrides the other.

In your case you need to distinguish two concepts: *build* environment vs. *run* environment.

### Build environment

Your build needs to execute on some environment. It's important to have appropriate dependencies for running tests, etc. Obviously, tests won't run if you supply MacOS lib on Windows.

### Run environment

It seems you have a requirement to create a separate distribution for each of the run environments. While tests can only run on a single build environment, you can bundle different jars to create different distributions from a single build.

### Environment-specific tests

How important are you tests? Is it possible that some functionality is environment-specific and might break on a different OS? If that is true, you should just have two different builds and each distribution should be compiled, tested and packaged on its environment to ensure the tests are run properly. If that is the case, just keep your build as it is and ensure your CI server has at least one build agent per environment. Configure CI to always run this build once per environment, then simply pick final build results from both builds. This is clearly extra effort, but if your tests are important, it'll pay off in the long run.

### No environment-specific tests

The alternative solution is to have one build environment, run any tests you might have only against that environment, but generate multiple distribution packages. I recommend splitting your project into three projects for this:

1. "core" with the common parts
2. "windows" distribution project with the windows-specific parts
3. "mac" distribution project with the macos-specific parts

Create those environment projects even if the only difference is those SWT libraries. You **CAN** keep all of this as one project, but it'll likely be more pain than it's worth.

Subsequently:

1. In core `pom.xml`: ensure core project generates proper jar. It'll need some dependency to compile, so you create one profile per **build** environment (you might have just one build environment, in that case no profile necessary) and in each profile define appropriate dependency with `<scope>provided</scope>` to ensure it's only used for compilation/testing.
2. In windows/macos `pom.xml`: in each add dependency on both core and environment-specific libs (SWT in this case) with default scope. Your existing assembly plugin configuration will be moved to these two projects.

When you run builds, you only specify profile of the build environment, but you get both distribution packages every time.

Comment: If you go with the three projects, remember that you need to put them as submodules of a root aggregate project. They don't necessarily need to use the root as parent. The root should have `pom` packaging and `modules` section, but otherwise can be pretty much empty.

Comment: Thanks Anton. Above solution helped me to create 2 jars.